# how to combine two dataset to one xml file

Tags: c#

how to combine two dataset to one  xml file

and how to read this after ?

i have this:

```
dsView1 = new DataSet("1");
SQL = "SELECT * FROM ConfTbl";
adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsView1, "ConfTbl");
adp.Dispose();
dsView2 = new DataSet("2");
SQL = "SELECT * FROM DipTbl";
adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(SQL, Conn);
adp.Fill(dsView2, "ConfTbl");
adp.Dispose();
dsView.WriteXml(@"d:\Test.xml");
```

how to combine dsView1 and dsView2 to one dataset, that i have table[0] and table[1]

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this it works fine.

```
dsView2.Tables[0].TableName="TableName";
dsView1.Tables.Add(dsView2.Tables[0].Copy());
```

Comment: thanks for the help, i try it and table1 is diferent than table2 (not the same filed) and i dont see table2 only table 1. what can be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to combine the two datasets

```
dsView1.Tables.Add(dsView2.Tables(0));
```

Comment: @Gali You mean it doesn't put `dsView2` into `dsView1`?

Comment: i got this error: DataTable already belongs to another DataSet.